# How can I know that if a program is running | C++

Tags: winapi

I made a function to start a game by my code, now I want to know if that game is still running, how can do that?

This is my function:

```
bool StartApp(const std::string& Name)
{
    std::wstring FileName = std::wstring(Name.begin(), Name.end());
    ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", FileName.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Use `CreateProcess` instead of `ShellExecute` and you can use the process handle to monitor the new process. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-processes

Comment: alternatively use [EnumProcesses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocesses) to look for your exe

Comment: FYI, `std::wstring(Name.begin(), Name.end())` is the not correct way to convert a `std::string` into a `std::wstring`. Use `MultiByteToWideChar()` or equivalent instead. Also, there is no need to do that conversion at all if you use the `A` version of the API, ie `ShellExecuteA()`, `CreateProcessA()`, etc

Comment: @AndersK That's not an alternative. It's what you have to make do with if you don't have a handle to the process in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ShellExecuteEx`. You can acquire a handle for the process (`SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS`).

Then you can check with `GetExitCodeProcess` or `WaitForSingleObject` if the process ist still running.

Don't forget to call `CloseHandle` if there is no need to wait any longer, or the process was closed.

Comment: Why recommend `ShellExecuteEx` over `CreateProcess`? There doesn't seem to be a convincing reason to get the Shell involved.

Comment: @IInspectable it makes sense to invoke the Shell only if `Name` can refer to a data file instead of an executable. But if `Name` is always an executable then I agree with you, use `CreateProcess()` instead.

Comment: Why call ShellExecuteEx to get it to call CreateProcess. Just call CreateProcess directly.